# Android: make a DNS query to resolve a domain name to IP address

Tags: android, android-networking

How do I make a DNS query to convert a host name to an IP address in Android app?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm new to Android and I googled "Android make DNS query", sadly I didn't find any good answer.

Comment: What kind of DNS query do you want to make? And try Java DNS query.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is a late late response. But I came here looking the same problem then I leave this solution for future.
My solution was using the [google's dns service](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). More specifically using the [json api version](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/doh/json):

For example, if you wish to know the MX record for brosoft.com.ar then you should make the following http requests:

> https://dns.google/resolve?name=brosoft.com.ar&type=a